# How to create a Text Node with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using lxml and python to manipulate xml files. I want to create a text node with no tags preferably, instead of creating a new `Element` and then append a text to it. How can I do that?

I could find an equivalent of this in `xml.dom.minidom` package of python called `createTextNode`, so I was wondering if lxml supports same functionality or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `lxml` doesn't provide a special API to create text node. You can simply set `text` property of a parent element to create or modify text node in that element, for example :

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> raw = '''<root><foo/></root>'''
>>> root = etree.fromstring(raw)
>>> root.text = 'bar'
>>> etree.tostring(root)
'<root>bar<foo/></root>'
```